# webservices using nusoap

Tags: php, nusoap

i am using nusoap for webservices to intigrate hotel api into my web application.

I create soapclient and called webservice.
request is

```
POST /API/xyz.asmx HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: NuSOAP/0.6.3
Host: xyz.com
Authorization: xyz
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="ISO-8859-1"
Content-Length: 646
SOAPAction: "xyz"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"  xmlns:si="http://soapinterop.org/xsd"><SOAP-ENV:Body>
<username xsi:type="xsd:string">xyz</username>xxx000000</hotel_id></ns1:getwebservice>
```

and response is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Date: Tue, 31 May 2011 07:18:28 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 387

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><Get_hotel_infoResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><getwebservice><hotels xmlns="" /></getwebserviceResult></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
</SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I am getting the xml response empty in response i.e   ,so how could i get the xml data in response.

I am not getting the xmlns link in response. so how will it come?

Comment: check documentation for that specific api whatever you are using.

Comment: In your request, you don't appear to have closed your `<SOAL-ENV:Envelope>` or `<SOAP-ENV:body>` tags. Or have you just copy+pasted it wrong?

Comment: sorry i pasted it wrong,just edited look at that code.

Comment: by the way -- you don't need to use `<pre>` tags and entities to get code to show up in SO questions; just indent your code by 4 spaces and SO will format it nicely for you.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use NuSOAP, it's long dead. Use PHP's integrated `SoapClient`.

Comment: for me, SoapClient from PHP is really bad. only error (than SOAPUI no error) with the same wsdl. NuSoap is good